# I'm trying to dynamically update a ul tag without touching the HTML drectly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update a ul tag without having to manually update the HTML.

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>Ruby</li>
        <li>Python</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    let currentText = document.querySelectorAll('.list  li').innerText;
    console.log(currentText);
    let nextText = currentText + '!';
    document.querySelectorAll('.list > li').innerText = nextText;
</script>
```

Comment: Your 2 querySelectorAll's are different, and you should be able to just select `li` if there's only 1 list. Then you have to loop through the selection.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an HTML collection. A collection has no innerText

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.list > li').forEach(function(elem) { console.log(elem.textContent); });`

Comment: You should avoid using `forEach` on a HTML collection as it's an array method (there's more to it here: https://medium.com/@larry.sassainsworth/iterating-over-an-html-collection-in-javascript-5071f58fad6b). A `for` loop would be better, otherwise I agree with everything epascarello has said. `querySelectorAll` requires an index i.e. `document.querySelectorAll('.list  li')[i].innerText`. Then use a standard `for` loop to increment `i`